# Why aren't instance properties available in `getOwnPropertyNames`?

Tags: javascript, typescript

Consider this sample class:

```
class Test {
    static staticProperty = `static property`;
    static staticMethodArrow = () => console.log(`static method arrow`);
    static staticMethodTraditional() {
        console.log(`static method traditional`);
    }
    
    instanceProperty = `instance property`;
    instanceMethodArrow = () => console.log(`instance method arrow`);
    instanceMethodTraditional() {
        console.log(`instance method traditional`);
    }
}
```

If we run `Object.getOwnPropertyNames(Test)` it returns all the static methods and properties as expected:

```
['length', 'name', 'prototype', 'staticMethodTraditional', 'staticProperty', 'staticMethodArrow']
```

If we run `Object.getOwnPropertyNames(Test.prototype)` I would expect the result to be:

```
['constructor', 'instanceMethodTraditional', 'instanceProperty', 'instanceMethodArrow']
```

However, it is actually just this:

```
['constructor', 'instanceMethodTraditional']
```

Why doesn't `Test.prototype` have all the instance methods and properties we've defined, and how can we get their names (ideally without having to instantiate a `new Test()`)?

Comment: Instance properties (including function-valued properties) go on the instance, not the prototype.  The only way to get their names is to get an instance.  See the linked q/a for more info.

Comment: @jcalz I think he also wants to know why non static class methods are not enumerable members of the prototype which the linked answer doesn't address AFAICT.

Comment: ? I don't see that in this question; the non-static class method is indeed present in `Object.getOwnPropertyNames()`, regardless of enumerability.

Comment: Looks like I don't know how to read.

Comment: There is no property `prototype` in JS. In browsers you can access it by property `__proto__`, or use `Object.getPrototypeOf`.

Comment: "There is no property `prototype` in JS"?  Class constructors certainly do have a [`prototype`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/prototype) property.  Maybe you mean that *instances* don't have a `prototype` property, but nobody here is asking for that or talking about that.